# Nx incremental build for TypeScript packages in watch mode

Tags: typescript, nrwl-nx

There is a Nx workspace using just the Nx core (no plugins) with a few buildable TypeScript packages and one web app (a Next.js app).

All TypeScript packages have the following NPM scripts to build and watch for file changes:

```json
{
  "main": "./build",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf ./build && tsc -p ./tsconfig.build.json",
    "dev": "npm run build -- --watch"
  },
  ...
}
```

The web app (Next.js) has dependencies on the packages and uses the following (default) scripts:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  ...
}
```

Since the workspace packages are incrementally built to be consumed by other packages and apps, how can I run the web app for development and watch/build file changes in the affected packages?

```sh
# Using the command like this (where "mywebapp" is the name of the web app)
nx run mywebapp:dev
```

Comment: Hey Romel, did you find any solution?

Comment: I was trying to come up with a solution but watch mode is very complex or not practical for incremental builds https://nx.dev/ci/incremental-builds